# Which of the three installed PyQt DLL directories do I want?

Tags: python, installation, pyqt, dll

I've tried installing Python and Qt several times but keep running into the same problem:  The examples included in the PyQt4 installation fail to run.  In my latest attempt I used the instructions found [here](http://kamiawz.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/how-to-install-and-configure-pyqt-in-windows/), and installed Python 3.1.3 and PyQt 4.8.3 for Python 3.1, all are the 32-bit versions.

I'm running WinXP with SP3 on a Dell M65 (T7200, 2GB Ram).

My installation directories are: ***C:\Python31*** and ***C:\Qt\2010.05*** (Both of these are the defaults from the respective install programs.)

After attempting to run ***score.py*** from the ***C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\demos\qtdemo*** directory I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\demos\qtdemo\score.py", line 43, in 
    from colors import Colors
  File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\demos\qtdemo\colors.py", line 45, in 
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

There are several answers provided for a similar error message in [**this** stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui), but none of them seems to be the answer to my problem.

I have verified all the directories in my env.path are correct and searched the local drives for any ***qt*.dll*** in other system directories--there are none in any directories other than the installation directory trees listed above.

However, most of the ***qt*.dll*** files found on the local drive have three copies, each with a different size and creation date.  The three directories (and modified dates) that show up most are: ***C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin*** (11/11/2010), ***C:\Qt\2010.05\bin*** (8/24/2010), and ***C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin*** (9/13/2010).  For example, the sizes of QtGui4.dll are 7757kb, 8080kb, and 9584kb, respectively.

It seems that the wrong dll is being loaded, so in what order should I put the directories in my PATH?  They are currently in the following order:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32; C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin; C:\Qt\2010.05\bin; C:\Qt\2010.05\mingw\bin; C:\Python31; C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin;
```

Comment: You don't need to install Qt yourself. As you can see, PyQt brings it's own versions - so why not try putting that first in the PATH?

Comment: Consider the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616834/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install Qt yourself. As you can see, PyQt brings it's own versions - so why not try putting that first in the PATH?