# Error: Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt' while importing pandas

Tags: python, qt, pandas

I use PyCharm Pro 2016.1.4 and pandas 18.1. I'm running into an issue whenever I import pandas. It happened after I updated PyCharm Pro (from 2016.1.3) and IPython 5.

Here's what the console shows me when I start it and then import pandas:

```
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 51602 51603
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
PyDev console: using IPython 4.0.1

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Abc\\Dev\\Code\\abc'])

Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
In[2]: import pandas
Backend Qt4Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 544, in do_enable_gui
    enable_gui(guiname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 509, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 194, in enable_qt4
    from pydev_ipython.inputhookqt4 import create_inputhook_qt4
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\inputhookqt4.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pydev_ipython.qt_for_kernel import QtCore, QtGui
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\qt_for_kernel.py", line 80, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 241, in load_qt
    result = loaders[api]()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 165, in import_pyqt4
    import sip
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with Qt DLL version conflicts.  I was able to get it working by doing
`conda update --all`

This seems to have fixed a missing dependancy: I see a copy of QtCore4.dll in C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin and C:\Anaconda3\Library\lib that weren't there before.

Based on the research below, other people copy QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll to C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin,  or they delete other path's from their environment

Here is some background:

[Cannot import PyQt4.QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui)

[iPython/jupyter qtconsole fails to start in anaconda 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008610/ipython-jupyter-qtconsole-fails-to-start-in-anaconda-2-4-0)

[PyQt4 Need to move DLLs to package root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616834/pyqt4-need-to-move-dlls-to-package-root)

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/540

Comment: how to disable this feature?